# Changing Default programs for a particular file type

Tags: default-programs

Another answer recommended "*Right click on the .torrent file...*" or "*Firefox go to Edit > Preferences > Applications change default application for magnet*"

What do I do if I can't find the .torrent file? Where does my system put these by default (as far as I know I haven't changed the default location)?

When I try to change the Firefox default application for magnet, I just get a file browser. Where do I point it? Where does Ubuntu store my programs, and what are their names? In Windows I'd look in "programs" for an .exe file with the same name as the program I want to use, what do I look for in Ubuntu?

Comment: Look in the /usr/bin directory for your favourite torrent application.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I do if I can't find the .torrent file?

**I would check your downloads folder for the `.torrent` file.** Unless you have changed it--which you would probably remember having done--this is the `Downloads`folder inside your home folder.

A `.torrent` file is not the same thing as a [metalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalink). Although some BitTorrent programs support pasting in the URL of a `.torrent` file as though it were a metalink, a `.torrent` file is an actual file that can be downloaded to your computer and contains the important information about how to download a torrent.

Files you download in a web  browser are usually downloaded to the same location even if they are different types of file (unless you specified different locations at the time you downloaded each one). Thus the `.torrent` file is probably in the same folder that any other file you download in your web browser would end up in, which is typically your `Downloads`folder.

Answer (score 0):

The default for magnet links is `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk`. Transmission stores torrent files in `.config/transmission/torrents`,
and, if you tell us what program you want to change it to, we might be able to help a little more.